# Display area of a jComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have this jComboBox on my application.  However, some times when I open it, the drop down area is too small to fit all the information that it is suppose to show.  Is there any work about so that the drop down area widens to accommodate all the information that it needs to show without increasing the size of the jComboBox?

Thank you.

Comment: How to you populate the JComboBox?

Comment: @Mohamed Saligh: I am using jDeveloper 11g.@

Comment: @dacwe: Populate a ResultSet and load it using jComboBoxModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually going to release this code on my blog this weekend. Here is an early release (I'll update the posting with the real link later). The benefit of this approach is that the functionality is supported by a listener so it should work on any LAF that extends the BasicComboPopop and you don't need to extend any classes. You can just use it like:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox( items );
BoundsPopupMenuListener listener = new BoundsPopupMenuListener(true, false);
comboBox.addPopupMenuListener( listener );
```

Edit: Check out [Combo Box Popup](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/) for the final code.

Comment: Hey, what is the address to your blog?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for Stepped Combo.

The basic idea here is to customize `Combobox` UI by extending `MetalComboBoxUI`

[**Here is a  sample code**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/SteppedComboBoxExample.htm)